# div hide and show in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I create a Road divider animation with one animating after another immediately? please find the following link for issue example
 http://jsfiddle.net/shantnuraj/36XeK/1/

**HTML**:

```
<div id="tech-slideshow">
    <div id="tech-slideshow-1" class="tech-slideshow-1">dfsd</div>
    <div id="tech-slideshow-2" class="tech-slideshow-1">dfs</div>
    <div id="tech-slideshow-3" class="tech-slideshow-1">dfsd</div>
    <div id="tech-slideshow-4" class="tech-slideshow-1">dfs</div>
    <div id="tech-slideshow-5" class="tech-slideshow-1">fsd</div>
    <div id="tech-slideshow-6" class="tech-slideshow-1">dfs</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.devider-marque img.devider {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
#tech-slideshow {
    height: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    bottom: 0;
}
#tech-slideshow > div {
    width: 50px;
    background:#000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 50px;
}
#tech-slideshow-1 {
    margin-top: -200px;
    -webkit-animation: moveSlideshow1 5s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: moveSlideshow1 5s linear infinite;
}
#tech-slideshow-2 {
    margin-top: -400px;
    -webkit-animation: moveSlideshow2 5s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: moveSlideshow1 5s linear infinite;
}
#tech-slideshow-3 {
    margin-top: -600px;
    -webkit-animation: moveSlideshow3 5s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: moveSlideshow1 5s linear infinite;
}
#tech-slideshow-4 {
    margin-top: -800px;
    -webkit-animation: moveSlideshow4 5s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: moveSlideshow1 5s linear infinite;
}
#tech-slideshow-5 {
    margin-top: -1000px;
    -webkit-animation: moveSlideshow5 5s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: moveSlideshow1 5s linear infinite;
}
#tech-slideshow-6 {
    margin-top: -1200px;
    -webkit-animation: moveSlideshow6 5s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: moveSlideshow1 5s linear infinite;
}
 @-moz-keyframes moveSlideshow1 {
 0% {top:0; height:150px;}
 10% {top:20;height:150px;}
 100% {top:1200px;height:150px;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes moveSlideshow1 {
 0% {top:0; height:150px;}
 10% {top:20;height:150px;}
 100% {top:1200px;height:150px;}
}
```

Comment: put some code in your post or people here close it with downvotes.

Comment: and explain what the issue is.

Comment: [How to ask questions in stackoverflow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Here is your answer with fiddle

use transition-delay instead of margin-top

```
#Anydiv {
     animation-name: moveSlideshow1;
     animation-duration: 5s;
     animation-iteration-count: infinite;
     animation-timing-function: linear;
     animation-delay: 1s; [ adding transition delay +1 to next div in loop will make it smoother ]
}
```

i have just edited fiddle in hurry so i have added animation parameter seperately you can use shorthand :)

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/krunalp1993/36XeK/4/

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: Thanks Dude Krunal Panchal.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can control the speed by setting animation time value.

```
 -webkit-animation: moveSlideshow6 3s linear infinite;
-moz-animation: moveSlideshow1 3s linear infinite;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.
but when my last div is hide then my loop is going start. i want show regularly. without break.. like smooth show again and again

Comment: Check my answer And also fiddle it works smoothly.. :)